# How can we define a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading on sl2

Tags: lie-algebras, graded-algebras

Let $sl_{2}$ be $2 \times 2$ traceless matrices over field $K$ of characteristic $0$. How can we define a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading on $sl_{2}$?

Let consider $h ,e ,f$ as follows respectively:
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
then the grading $L_{-1}=\mathbb{K}h$ , $L_{0}=\mathbb{K}h , \mathbb{K}f$ and $L_{i}=0$ for all $ i \notin \{-1,0,1\}$. How can it be considered as $\mathbb{Z}$-graded?

Comment: You always have the trivial grading (everything has degree 0), but maybe this is not what you want. Hint: find $s$ such that $\mathrm{ad}(s)$ has integral eigenvalues (and not all zero).

Comment: What is integral eigenvalues?

Comment: eigenvalues in $\mathbf{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for $L=\bigoplus L_i$ to be $\mathbb{Z}$-graded, you need $[L_i,L_j]\subseteq L_{i+j}$, or in other words $[x,y]\in L_{i+j}$ whenever we have $x\in L_i$ and $y\in L_j$. In this case, we may define

$$ L_{-1}=Ke \qquad L_0=Kh \qquad L_1=Kf. $$

(And $L_i=0$ otherwise.) To check it is $\mathbb{Z}$-graded, it suffices to check the commutator conditions for the basis elements. For example, $e\in L_{-1}$ and $h\in L_0$ so we ought to have $[e,h]\in L_{-1}$. Is this true?

If you want, you can make a $3\times 3$ table of commutators $[x,y]$ of basis elements $x,y\in\{e,h,f\}$, and then check each entry is in the correct graded component in this way. A couple other observations you can make: all diagonal entries are $0$, so they are all in the correct graded component (why?), and if an off-diagonal entry is in the correct graded component then the correponding entry on the other side of the diagonal is also in the correct graded component (why?).